# Compile Python using py2exe in 64 bit machine

Tags: python

I have made sure I use python 64 bit, wxpython 64 bit and py2exe 64 bit, and I am compiling a simple print "hello" code to exe using py2exe with a setup.py that I need your help with, this is what setup.py looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

manifest = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="0.64.1.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="Controls"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>Your Application</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
"""

"""
installs manifest and icon into the .exe
but icon is still needed as we open it
for the window icon (not just the .exe)
changelog and logo are included in dist
"""

setup(
    windows = [
        {
            "script": "module2.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "logo.ico")],
            "other_resources": [(24,1,manifest)]
        }
    ],
      data_files=["logo.ico"]
)
```

After I compile and run the generated exe, it says

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\User...

R6034

An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I search and found similar problems in SO but none solve my problems, because most users are using 32 bit machine while mine is 64 bit machine that wanting to compile into 64 bit exe. I have made sure py2exe is 64 bit, but I can't find a manifest file thats for 64 bit even in py2exe samples (the py2exe 64 bit package contains 32 bit manifest sample).

How do I specify a correct manifest for py2exe 64 bit to compile to 64 bit exe

Comment: I'm guessing `processorArchitecture="x86"` should be `x64` at least.

Comment: I tried, and it also gives the same error

Comment: I don't have a 64-bit machine, and I don't know much about py2exe either - but x64 looks wrong, normally it's x86_64.

Comment: hi jazzpi thanks for the help, but it still does not works

Comment: You might want to change `type="win32"` to `type="win64"` as well (And make sure you have a 64 bit windows running ;) ).

Comment: tried changing X86_64 + win64 tried also X86 + win64, but still not working. The errors become "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.". I am not sure how to use sxstrace.exe

Comment: I am giving up and move to Gui2exe and it works fine